# admin panel setup for mean stack app

Tags: mean-stack

I am building an e-commerce website which will require continuous updation of products, so for that I need t setup admin panel for the website. My app is based on MEAN stack. Now, I am confused on how to handle session for admin panel and website and also how to configure the admin panel. My application is almost ready only admin panel is left.

1. Do I need to handle sessions separately for admin panel and website and if yes how ? Currently I am using node-passport for sessions.
2. how can I use subdomain to open admin panel, for eg. I have a domain called www.abc.com, Now I want to use admin.abc.com and in that case I want to redirect user to the admin panel. How can I create sub domain ? and How can I handle this in my MEAN app ?

Comment: You should actually set a `role` when you authenticate the user. This can help in identifying between a normal user and an admin. Once that is known, you can show the admin panel. Try setting the user role in sessions.

Comment: I am already doing that, I have specified that only user with specific role can access admin panel, but what will happen in following case - If a user logs in to the admin panel and also to the website (with different ids), how can I maintain sessions in that case ?

Comment: When you access your page with two different id's , then its going to be two separate sessions right? First of all, is your admin panel going to a separate page ? Can a user be both an admin and a user ?

Comment: No a user can have only one role, but suppose a user is logged in my website and in another tab he opens admin panel and logs into that with different id, then how does node passport handles that. two sessions in one browser.